# CRUD operations vs Queries

Tags: database, cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, crud

I thought that crud operations were performed by queries.  What exactly is a query in this case?  Here it seems to imply something different:

For example:
“**The typical patterns of Cassandra usage are actually more of the CRUD [create, read, update and delete] workloads than queries**. **All of the CRUD functionality is working, the querying capabilities are working**. We’ve taken a few canonical tier one workloads on Cassandra and made sure that we’ve got everything covered and we will monitor customer workloads and address the last mile things to take it to general availability.”

above quote from:
https://thenewstack.io/microsofts-cosmos-db-adds-apis-become-compatible-cassandra/

Comment: Could you share a link?

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: It refers to the fact that Cassandra has limited support for complex queries like joins, nested select statements and other queries that are executed traditionally on sql. The operations in Cassandra are more simpler and oriented towards your data model.